# Angular post request not showing any response data

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, django-rest-framework

when i send post request with postman i got expected response with status 400
but when i send request with browser using angular http.post i got only 400 error without response data
[image: here is my postman request with response]

[image: here is my browser request without response]

here is the request i sending with angular

```
signUp(data: {}) {
return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + '/blog/api/user/', data).pipe(
  map(resp => resp),
  catchError(err => {
    throw err;
  })
)}
```

here i console.log my response

```
    onSubmit() {
    if (!this.signupForm.valid) {
      return;
    }
    this.authService.signUp(this.signupForm.value)
    .subscribe(
      resp => console.log(resp),
      err => console.log(err)
    );
  }
```

Comment: Bad request could mean you're sending data that isn't what is expected in the backend (maybe wrong property names, or different object structure). Can you print your `data` and see if it's what the backend expects? also try: `this.http.post(this.baseUrl + '/blog/api/user/', data,  {observe: 'response'})` to get the full POST response

Comment: i added {observe: 'response'} but it's give me same response

Comment: and actually i write backend myself using django-rest-framework

Comment: What does the backend expect from your request? And what does the data you send actually look like compared to that?

Comment: backend expect data like this {username: somename, email: some@email, password: somepassword} and i also giving data like this and backend check if username is allready exists it will give error like this `{ "username": ["a user with that username allready exists"] }` with status 400

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove pipe in your service like this to see if it work

```
signUp(data: {}) {
  return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + '/blog/api/user/', data).pipe(
    map(resp => resp),
    catchError(err => {
      throw err;
    })
)}
```

Change to this

```
signUp(data: {}) {
  return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + '/blog/api/user/', data);
}
```

Normally we use operator in component to modify data come from API

in your component do like this

```
this.authService.signUp(this.signupForm.value)
   .pipe(
        map(resp => resp),
        catchError(err => {
          throw err;
        })
    )
    .subscribe(
      resp => console.log(resp),
      err => console.log(err)
    );
```

Comment: i tried also like this without operator but not getting response

Comment: How did you return reponse from your API ? Also check my answer again